# I want to calculate the eigenvalues of a 2x2 matrix in Mathematica where the matrix elements are functions

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica, eigenvalue

I am fairly new to Mathematica. I want to calculate the eigenvalues of a 2x2 matrix, where the matrix elements are functions of 2 variables. The code that I am using is given below :

```
\[Phi] = Pi/4, t1 = 1, t2 = 1/3, U;
f1[k1_, k2_] := Cos[\[Phi] + Sqrt[3] * k2] + Cos[\[Phi] - 3 k1/2 - Sqrt[3] k2/2] + Cos[\[Phi] + 3 k1/2 - Sqrt[3] k2/2], f1[k1_, k2_] := Cos[\[Phi] - Sqrt[3] * k2] + Cos[\[Phi] + 3 k1/2 + Sqrt[3] k2/2] + Cos[\[Phi] - 3 k1/2 + Sqrt[3] k2/2];
g[k1_, k2_] := Exp[-\[ImaginaryJ] k1] + 2 Cos[Sqrt[3]* k2/2] Exp[-\[ImaginaryJ]  k1/2];
mat[k1_, k2_] = {{U - 2 *t2 * f1, t1*g}, {t1*Conjugate[g],  2 *t2 * f2 - U}};
Eigenvalues[mat]
```

So as you can see from the code, I have three functions f1, f2 and g which has two arguments k1 and k2 and their forms are given. The matrix I need to diagonalize is mat. I need to obtain the eigenvalues in an analytical form and later plot them wrt k1 and k2. But after this code snippet, when I try to run this, I am not getting anything, i.e., nothing is coming in output. How do I sort this out?

Answer (score 1):

```
f1[k1_, k2_] := Cos[ϕ + Sqrt[3]*k2] + Cos[ϕ - 3 k1/2 - Sqrt[3] k2/2] +
   Cos[ϕ + 3 k1/2 - Sqrt[3] k2/2]

f1[k1_, k2_] := Cos[ϕ - Sqrt[3]*k2] + Cos[ϕ + 3 k1/2 + Sqrt[3] k2/2] +
   Cos[ϕ - 3 k1/2 + Sqrt[3] k2/2]

g[k1_, k2_] := Exp[-\[ImaginaryJ] k1] +
   2 Cos[Sqrt[3]*k2/2] Exp[-\[ImaginaryJ] k1/2];

mat[k1_, k2_] := {{U - 2*t2*f1, t1*g}, {t1*Conjugate[g], 2*t2*f2 - U}}

form = Eigenvalues[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]
```

> {1/2 (a + d - Sqrt[a^2 + 4 b c - 2 a d + d^2]),
> 1/2 (a + d + Sqrt[a^2 + 4 b c - 2 a d + d^2])}

```
ϕ = Pi/4;
t1 = 1;
t2 = 1/3;

{{a, b}, {c, d}} = mat[k1, k2]
```

> {{-((2 f1)/3) + U, g}, {Conjugate[g], (2 f2)/3 - U}}

```
FullSimplify[form]
```

> {1/3 (-f1 + f2 - Sqrt[(f1 + f2 - 3 U)^2 + 9 g Conjugate[g]]),
> 1/3 (-f1 + f2 + Sqrt[(f1 + f2 - 3 U)^2 + 9 g Conjugate[g]])}

Answer (score 1):

Carefully compare this, character by character, with what you have

```
ϕ=Pi/4;t1=1;t2=1/3;
f1[k1_,k2_]:=Cos[ϕ+Sqrt[3]*k2]+Cos[ϕ-3 k1/2-Sqrt[3] k2/2]+Cos[ϕ+3 k1/2-Sqrt[3] k2/2];
f2[k1_,k2_]:=Cos[ϕ-Sqrt[3]*k2]+Cos[ϕ+3 k1/2+Sqrt[3] k2/2]+Cos[ϕ-3 k1/2+Sqrt[3] k2/2];
g[k1_,k2_]:=Exp[-\[ImaginaryJ] k1]+2 Cos[Sqrt[3]*k2/2] Exp[-\[ImaginaryJ] k1/2];
mat[k1_,k2_]:={{U-2*t2*f1[k1,k2],t1*g[k1,k2]},{t1*Conjugate[g[k1,k2]],2*t2*f2[k1,k2]-U}};
Eigenvalues[mat[k1,k2]]
```

And then check the output very carefully to try to verify if it is correct or not.

Comment: `FullSimplify[Eigenvalues[mat[k1,k2]]]` took about 100 seconds on my setup.